# Does any pelias service needs wof bundles to work?

Tags: pelias

I have downloaded wof data with import place. As a result, i have ended up having meta and data directories created by pelias/whosonfirst data importer. I imported these directories with pelias import wof command. Now, I am not sure whether I can delete these directories or not.

I have looked up to pelias docs and got confused about what to do. At first, I see at [pelias/pelias](https://github.com/pelias/pelias). I thought that only elasticSearch file would be enough for all services. How pelias works [part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuhJt.png) made me think like that. Later on, I came across the the [pelias/docker](https://github.com/pelias/docker) page and see that there is a [section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqd7v.png) describing cleaning up temporary files. There was no suggestion for deleting whosonfirst data bundles. Therefore, I thought that whosonfirst data bundles are necessary for pelias.

While reading the [full planet considerations](https://github.com/pelias/documentation/blob/master/full_planet_considerations.md) for pelias, I came across a [section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0W17v.png) suggesting using different clusters for importing data and geocoding. In that section, taking a snapshot of elasticsearch index and loading it to a different cluster for geocoding is suggested. This made me think that just elasticsearch index is enough for all the pelias services.

At this point, I wonder deleting wof files would have an effect on pelias services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the [pip-service](https://github.com/pelias/pip-service) requires who's on first data to exist on disk.

It loads WOF data directly from the individual `.geojson` files or `sqlite` database on startup, so the files must be present permanently or you can't restart the service.